# In Azure Devops release pipelines AzCopy --overwrite=ifSourceNewer will not copy anything over, even when file does not exist

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-storage-account

Using the Azure DevOps pipelines, I am trying to do an `azcopy copy` just for files over that have a newer modified date.
Either way I am not having any luck now, even after reading the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-ref-azcopy-copy
In theory using `azcopy copy source dest --overwrite=ifSourceNewer` should do what I need. After unsuccessful trials, I ran over to google to try and find some answer, but at no avail.

Anyone have any ideas? Below you can find the logs:

```
2022-02-01T12:35:36.8852853Z ##[command] & "AzCopy\AzCopy.exe" copy "D:\a\r1\a\**" "https://storageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/containername"  --overwrite=ifSourceNewer
2022-02-01T12:35:36.9315258Z INFO: Scanning...
2022-02-01T12:35:36.9317962Z INFO: Authenticating to destination using Azure AD
2022-02-01T12:35:37.1414889Z INFO: AzCopy.exe: A newer version 10.13.0 is available to download
2022-02-01T12:35:37.1415562Z 
2022-02-01T12:35:37.2768789Z INFO: Any empty folders will not be processed, because source and/or destination doesn't have full folder support
2022-02-01T12:35:37.2897185Z 
2022-02-01T12:35:37.2898670Z Job xyz has started
2022-02-01T12:35:37.2900352Z Log file is located at: C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.azcopy\xyz.log
2022-02-01T12:35:37.2900854Z 
2022-02-01T12:35:37.2900975Z 
2022-02-01T12:35:37.2901107Z 
2022-02-01T12:35:37.2901227Z 
2022-02-01T12:35:37.2901721Z Job xyzsummary
2022-02-01T12:35:37.2902255Z Elapsed Time (Minutes): 0
2022-02-01T12:35:37.2902752Z Number of File Transfers: 0
2022-02-01T12:35:37.2903214Z Number of Folder Property Transfers: 0
2022-02-01T12:35:37.2903716Z Total Number of Transfers: 0
2022-02-01T12:35:37.2905656Z Number of Transfers Completed: 0
2022-02-01T12:35:37.2906210Z Number of Transfers Failed: 0
2022-02-01T12:35:37.2906722Z Number of Transfers Skipped: 0
2022-02-01T12:35:37.2907206Z TotalBytesTransferred: 0
2022-02-01T12:35:37.2907687Z Final Job Status: Completed
2022-02-01T12:35:37.2907918Z 
2022-02-01T12:35:37.3176255Z Uploaded files successfully from source path: 'D:\a\r1\a\**' to storage account: 'storageaccountname' in container: 'containername' with blob prefix: ''
2022-02-01T12:35:37.3257443Z ##[command] & "AzCopy\AzCopy.exe" logout
```

Comment: You are not using the latest version of AzCopy.

Comment: @Poiter well yes, but the base version for AzureFileCopy@4 is 10.8.0:
"What's new in Version 4.0: Support AzCopy.exe version 10.8.0"
Anyway, any idea how to update the version?

Answer (score 0):

Basically using the Azure DevOps (release) pipelines, the copy function using `Azcopy copy` is broken and will not copy anything if `--overwrite=ifSourceNewer` is used as an argument.

One way of solving this would be using `Azcopy sync` over an AzureCLI Task (https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/9157#issuecomment-871505530).

Basically this is how the task in yaml will look:

```
 - task: AzureCLI@2
   inputs:
   azureSubscription: <Your Service Connection>
   scriptType: pscore
   scriptLocation: inlineScript
   inlineScript: |
    Write-Host "Current Directory: $pwd"
    $env:AZCOPY_SPA_CLIENT_SECRET=$env:servicePrincipalKey
    azcopy login --service-principal --application-id $env:servicePrincipalId --tenant-id $env:tenantId              
    azcopy.exe sync "./drop" "$(staticWebsiteContainerUrl)" --delete-destination=true --recursive              
    $env:AZCOPY_SPA_CLIENT_SECRET=''
    $env:servicePrincipalKey=''
   addSpnToEnvironment: true
   workingDirectory: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
```

Hopefully it will help someone in the future.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks bot. I hope it is more understandable now.